# Issue with Plotting Counties Using spmap

Tags: plot, stata, cartography, cartogram

I am trying to plot the counties in the continental U.S. by a value that the counties have associated with them. I am using the `spmap` package. My shape files comes from:  https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html. I am using the 500k version.

```
capture ssc install spmap
capture ssc install shp2dta
```

I unzip the file. I then load the map as follows:

```
shp2dta using "cb_2015_us_county_500k.shp", database(county2015db) coordinates(county2015coord) replace
use county2015db, clear
destring STATEFP, replace
destring GEOID, replace
```

If I don't want to shade the counties, everything works perfectly:

```
spmap using county2015coord if STATEFP<60 & STATEFP!=2 & STATEFP!=15, id(GEOID)
```

However, only a handful of counties are filled in (and the map is much smaller and Alaska appears) if I do the following (just using _ID as the values for this toy example):

```
spmap _ID using county2015coord if STATEFP<60 & STATEFP!=2 & STATEFP!=15, id(GEOID) fcolor(Blues)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have used `_ID` in the `id( )` field instead of using `GEOID`. That solves the problem.